# How to compare a deck of cards with decks stored in database

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring Boot and MySQL on a project where I am using 3rd party web API to pull up a player's game logs and see which decks he has used in last 20 or so "battles".

For now, I have three tables, each labelled decks, deck_cards and cards. There are ~100 cards in the game, and each deck contains 8 of them. I classified the relationship as a many-to-many bidirectional relationship between Deck and Card entities since each deck contains more than one card, and each card can be assigned to many different decks. I went on to create deck_cards, which holds the primary key (id) of each table.

Now, the kind of information I can obtain from the API is the set of 8 cards each player has used in a battle. The JSON response includes the ids of cards, which make up the deck used in the battle. My only question is, I don't know how to check this deck against the decks already stored in db so that I don't store duplicates. Is there either a JPA/Spring Boot function or SQL statement that can help solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

```
public class Deck {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                })
    @JoinTable(name = "deck_cards",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "deck_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "card_id")})
    private Set<Card> cards = new HashSet<>();
    //...
}

public class Card {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
                },
                mappedBy = "cards")
    private Set<Deck> decks;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given data model and SQL you could do the following to obtain the deck_id of the deck containing the given cards. This only works when the cards are unique in a deck as they seem since you are using a set.

```
select deck_id
from deck_cards
where card_id in :cardids
group by deck_id
having count(*) = 8
```

Alternatively you could introduce a new column in the deck which contains all ids of the cards in the deck in ascending order filled to a fixed length.
So the deck of the first 8 cards would be something like: `0001020304050607` assuming the ids start with 0.

This string can easily constructed from 8 cards and used to check if that is in the database. You could even put a unique index on it.

Comment: Let me try this one out but it looks like it should work! Thank you :)